# Unable to re-render function on screen focused

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am implementing **DatePickerAndroid** in react native. My screen structure is defined using **BottomTabNavigator**. When I click the second tab for the first time, it renders the picker component. But on re-rendering it does not work.

I want to re-render the Date Picker component each time the screen/tab is clicked. But componentDidMount() works only for one time rendering.

I also tried **triggering an action with a 'didFocus' event listener**, but it gives error `cannot read property addListener of undefined`.

Here is my implementation.  https://snack.expo.io/ry584IZQr

Please help to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your prop `navigation` is not defined when you are mounting your component. That's why you are getting this error, you are trying to call a method on something that's undefined.

Comment: Can you please help specify with the exact code of line? I am unable to understand properly.

Comment: I only found 1 addListener in your example, so I'm assuming the error is here `this.focusListener = navigation.addListener()` in `Range.js` line 8.

Comment: I guess I have defined navigation prop already `const { navigation } = this.props;`

Comment: You have defined the variable inside the component yes. But are you passing the navigation prop to your component when you are using the ? ie:  `<Range navigation={your_value} />` ? This is probably what's missing.